# Is salt water impervious to emf frequency?

Tags: waves

Does the salt negate frequency when in liquid form.

Comment: Salt in liquid form and salt water are two different things....but consider that if salt water completely stopped any electromagnetic frequencies that it would not let any light through at all. As anyone can attest by going to the beach however is that salt water is very clear up to a certain depth

Answer (score 2):

Substances that are electrically conductive are usually good at blocking electromagnetic radiation when the wavelength is longer than that of infrared light. Since dissolved salt makes water conductive, salt water will block radio waves of most wavelengths. For very low radio frequencies (called *VLF*), the VLF radiation will penetrate salt water for a few tens of meters.